# Is a wildcard possible on redirect validation on a startup.cs file in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, nwebsec

While performing OAuth I have to redirect URLs like for example https://*.abc.com/admin/oauth/authorize?client_id=e97d...

(where * means it can be any dynamic word)
and while trying the below code it's not working

```
app.UseRedirectValidation(options => options.AllowedDestinations("https://*.abc.com/").AllowSameHostRedirectsToHttps());
```

I have referred to the document linked below, which does not mention anything regarding wildcard but I would like to know if any solution is possible except I know to to disable the validation from my startup file

https://docs.nwebsec.com/en/latest/nwebsec/Redirect-validation.html